# What is the meaning of single number in page section of APA citation

Tags: citation-style

My goal is to resubmit a paper to another journal, which has a  requirement to format all citations with APA style. I am using Google Scholar to get a first version of each citation in APA,  and want to make sure I understand what every part of the citation means.  In the following,  I have no problem understanding that the bold part means Volume 31, Issue 1 and pages ranging from 1 to 38.

> Fawcett, T. (2004). ROC graphs: Notes and practical considerations for researchers. Machine learning, **31**(1), **1-38**.

However, I cannot understand what the single, six digit number represents in the following citation.  Is this acceptable APA style? Shouldn't that be a range of pages instead of a single number?

> Mo, H., Sun, H., Liu, J., & Wei, S. (2019). Developing window behavior models for residential buildings using XGBoost algorithm. Energy and Buildings, 205, **109564**.

Also, I cannot understand the following. It seems to be Volume 8, Issue 4 but what about the bold part starting with **e**?

> Sagi, O., & Rokach, L. (2018). Ensemble learning: A survey. Wiley Interdisciplinary Reviews: Data Mining and Knowledge Discovery, 8(4), **e1249**.

Comment: Regarding "e1249", I am quite sure this refers to the article number. Some journals (usually those which are "online-only") give the published articles an article number. Additionally, in such cases each article might start from page 1 itself, so there is no "page range" for an article in any issue (although I suppose you could list the total number of pages as "1--N").

Comment: Looking at the journal "Energy and Buildings" on [ScienceDirect](https://www.sciencedirect.com/journal/energy-and-buildings/vol/205/suppl/C), it seems that 109564 is also the article number in this case. But the confusion is understandable, perhaps it's better if the citation said "Art. 109564" instead, or something similar.

Comment: [APA themselves](https://apastyle.apa.org/style-grammar-guidelines/references/examples/journal-article-references#2) write "If the journal article has an article number instead of a page range, include the word “Article” and then the article number instead of the page range."

Answer (score 1):

> Mo, H., Sun, H., Liu, J., & Wei, S. (2019). Developing window behavior models for residential buildings using XGBoost algorithm. Energy and Buildings, 205, **109564**.

This journal uses article numbers/identifiers, and then numbers pages 1 - n within each article.

> Sagi, O., & Rokach, L. (2018). Ensemble learning: A survey. Wiley Interdisciplinary Reviews: Data Mining and Knowledge Discovery, 8(4), **e1249**.

According to Wiley, the e-number is called [eLocator](https://authorservices.wiley.com/asset/photos/eLocators_text_for_author_site.pdf) and replaces the page number for electronic articles.